# UIGraphicsBeginImageContext vs CGBitmapContextCreate on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, core-graphics

This may be a really stupid question, but can someone tell me the difference between creating a CGContextRef using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext and using CGBitmapContextCreate for drawing to images?  Especially now since UIKit drawing is thread safe I was wondering if there was any reason to use CGBitmapContextCreate over UIGraphicsBeginImageContext.

Comment: "really stupid question"s don't usually get you +6 upvotes ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Apple's [UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/UIKitFunctionReference.pdf), which carries the cover date of the 15th November 2010, `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` and related functions should still be called on the main thread only. The same text is repeated in the developer documentation that comes with the latest Xcode, 3.2.5. However, it reports the same for `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` which I explicitly understood to be thread safe now. My understanding was that only `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` and the UIImage, UIColor and UIFont classes are now thread safe rather than the entirety of UIKit, but I'm unable to find a definitive reference.

Regardless, `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` is a UIKit wrapper that sits on top of `CGBitmapContextCreate` and reduces its functionality. In particular you're limited to RGBA colour space images with a fixed component order (though it varies according to the iOS version) and cannot specify your own target buffer for drawing. So, for example, it's useless for doing a bunch of CoreGraphics composition and then posting the result off to OpenGL and unhelpful for piping graphics you've already got in some array form into CoreGraphics.

However, where the UIKit method supports the functionality you need and is safe to use, there is no inherent advantage to the CoreGraphics methods.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009559-SW29 it says in the release notes that drawing to a graphics context is thread safe, you think their documentation is just inconsistent?  I've tried calling UIGraphicsBeginImageContext from a dispatch queue and it worked fine.  +1 for the detailed explanation, I thought it might just be a wrapper but was unsure, thanks again.

Comment: One more question, from your experience is one way faster than the other?  I would think going to down to the CG level would be faster, but don't know for sure.

Comment: The two things are inconsistent — I'll bet the release notes are more accurate though, as they were written specifically to highlight new features whereas the other documentation probably just hasn't been updated. I would expect direct CoreGraphics calls to have an extremely slight theoretical performance advantage over Objective-C calls, but nothing that could possibly matter. For UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, which is a C call, I wouldn't expect the difference to be measurable — the UIKit function will just call the CoreGraphics and the thing that costs will be the creation of the context.

Comment: Creating an offscreen context and rendering with CG... calls instead of UI... calls is not significantly hard in my opinion. I'd stick with the CG... methods to ensure thread safety.