# CGContextDrawRadialGradient in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I tried to draw a Gradient Dot, but the CGGradientCreateWithColors always returns nil.
I am new to Swift and Objective C (started today, but made some Apps with Xamarin).
Can please anyone explain what is wrong with the following code?

```
func initFields(){
    var startColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    var endColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    var colors: CFArray = [startColor, endColor]

    Gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors, [0, 10])
}
func DrawSomething(){
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size)
    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), Gradient!, TouchLocation!, 10, TouchLocation!, 10, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `CGGradientCreateWithColors()` documentation:

> ... each location must be a CGFloat value in the range of 0 to 1, inclusive.

So change `[0, 10]` to `[0, 1]` in the creation of the gradient.

The color at location 0 is mapped to the starting circle and the color at location 1
is mapped to the ending circle.

It also seems strange that the starting circle and the ending circle are identical
in your code.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpfull getting the Gradient. I changed the End Location for it too. But it doesn´t draw anything, is this all I have to do? Begin an ImageContext and call the Draw function?

Comment: @NormanSchütt: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` is used to draw into a bitmap (example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683448/uigraphicsbeginimagecontext-vs-cgbitmapcontextcreate). - For custom drawing in a UIView subclass, you implement `drawRect:`.